# socket.send and socket.recv, used one after another, lead to unsynchronized client-server communication Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, send, recv

I am trying to create something like a dialog between a server-client. The following explains it:

```
Client      +   Server
---------------------
send(foo)   |  recv(foo)
recv(bar)   |  send(bar)
send(foobar)|  recv(foobar)
recv(barfoo)|  send(barfoo)
etc.....................
```

So all I am trying to do is achieve a successful "dialog-like" exchange of messages, between a server and a client. The problem is that after a while on of the two endpoints will fall out of synchronization. That leads to a terminal running state that **both** sides paused their execution by trying to execute a blocking call of `send` or `recv`, without of course being able to.

Is there any operations I am missing?

I am creating the sockets with the following code (Python3)

For the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#server.py

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((str(address_port[0]), int(address_port[1])))
serversocket.listen()
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
msg_rcv = clientsocket.recv(1024)           # recv foo
clientsocket.send("foo".encode('ascii'))    # send bar
msg_rcv = clientsocket.recv(1024)           # recv foobar
clientsocket.send("foo".encode('ascii'))    # send barfoo
#etc...
```

For the client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#client.py

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect((host, port))
clientsocket.send("foo".encode('ascii'))    # send foo
msg_rcv = clientsocket.recv(1024)           # recv bar
clientsocket.send("foobar".encode('ascii')) # send foobar
msg_rcv = clientsocket.recv(1024)           # recv barfoo
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample works fine for me (once I added definitions for host, port, etc). Try to produce a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Also, you might consider adding print statements and see what you can do for yourself:  `send` then print what you sent.  `recv` then print what you received, etc.

Comment: @GilHamilton That's a minimal logic approach of my code. There are many of operations taking place between the sends and recv. The problem is that because there are many sends and recv, after a while client-server falls out of order. An example would be that the server is trying to read something that the client finished sending, the client moved on to the next receive, and the execution freezes there.

Comment: This is why a complete example that reproduces the problem is best. Having said that, your code has a common deficiency with beginner socket code that may well be the cause: you should never assume that when you `send`, all your data was sent. It is permissible for the system to only send part of the data (the return value tells you what was sent). Likewise, you cannot assume that each `recv` you execute receives *exactly* the bytes sent by a peer's individual `send`. You might receive *part* of a sent buffer, or you might receive *two* sent buffers concatenated into a single buffer.

Comment: @GilHamilton Sadly the code is way to big to refined and attached here. What you described though is the basic problem. Is there any way to stop the transmission that is taking place? I though of socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR), but after that there is no way of writing back to the socket. All the transmissions of data are correct. Both in length and content.

Comment: Yes, `shutdown` is permanent so not a solution. This issue is why "protocols" are created. There are multiple ways to implement this, but the usual one is to frame the data: first, you send a fixed-length binary field (say, 2 bytes long) that contains the length in bytes of the remaining "payload" field. On the other peer, you read exactly 2 bytes to get the length field, then you know how many subsequent bytes you need to read (which, remember, might require multiple `recv` calls). In conjunction, use python's `sendall` to ensure all bytes are actually sent.

Comment: @GilHamilton That indeed brought the communication into a balance. Thank you! But still i can't figure a way of checking that buffer, in a file transfer. The data sent into the buffer are binary, and I would have to establish a protocol using binary statemets. It seems tricky! I will work it more and post an answer if a find something solid!